# How to remove SQL pivot from a SQL view in Transact-SQL (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, sql-view

I have a view `LoanDocDtl`which is made from a pivot and it is causing performance issue. Whenever I query that view, it takes a lot of time to give me the result.

I tried to convert it into table but it still is slow.

```
create view dbo.LoanDocDtl
as
    select
        LoanId,
        DocUnknownCreateDtTm = [0],
        DocUnknownExistBit = convert(bit, case when [0] is not null then 1 else 0 end), 
        DocCertificateCreateDtTm = [1],
        DocCertificateExistBit = convert(bit, case when [1] is not null then 1 else 0 end), 
        DocDownloadCreateDtTm = [2],
        DocDownloadExistBit = convert(bit, case when [2] is not null then 1 else 0 end), 
        DocVerificationCreateDtTm = [225],
        DocVerificationExistBit = convert(bit, case when [225] is not null then 1 else 0 end)
    from (
        select
            LoanId,
            DocTypeId,
            CreateDtTm
        from LoanDoc --table
        where DocTypeId <> 0) a
    pivot (max(a.CreateDtTm)
        for DocTypeId
            in ([0], 
                [1], 
                [2], 
                [225])) as pvt;
go
```

There are 0 - 255 distinct `DocTypeId`, I have added only a few in the above code to minimize the view. The `LoanDoc` table has tons of `LoanId` and each `LoanId` has multiple `DocTypeId` attached to it, hence it is very slow.

Is there a way to optimize this by making this a table or populating this view using temp tables or by adding everything in a stored procedure and populating this view?

Comment: Views are not persistent, they are just a stored query. So "populating" it isn't possible. You could maybe store this data in a table but you still have to run this to populate it. And if the data needs to be real time that isn't going to do anything but make it even slower. Can you share the table definition (including indexes) and some sample data? Also the execution plan that is slow would be a big big plus.

Comment: @SeanLange - Actually, I got this figured out the moment you said indexes. There was a just one index on `LoanDoc` which was the primary key (a unique clustered index on 3 columns). I was able to get the query result pretty fast after creating 2 separate nonclustered indexes on `LoanId` and `DocTypeId`.